# "una clase de español" vs. "una clase española"

Tags: adjetivos, preposiciones

If *"una clase de español"* means "a Spanish class" and *"español / española"* can also be an adjective, is *"una clase española"* also a valid/common phrase?

Can we say that *"una clase de español"* roughly means "a class about the Spanish language" and *"una clase española"* roughly means "a class taught in Spanish"?

Similarly, what about *"un maestro de español"* vs. *"un maestro español"*? Is it valid/common? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While "Spanish lesson" and "Spanish teacher" are ambiguous in English (a lesson of Spanish language / a lesson of a Spanish sort // a teacher of Spanish language / a teacher of Spanish nationality), such ambiguity does not apply to Spanish.

We say:

- clase de español (NOT clase española)

and

- maestro/profesor de español (NOT maestro/profesor español, which can only be used to refer to a teacher born in Spain)

Comment: Thanks! It seems that in many cases _español_ as an adjective refers to the country Spain (_maestro español_) or the Spanish culture (_restaurante español_). Is it common to use _español_ as an adjective to refer to the Spanish language?

Comment: Well, you can of course say *el idioma español* or *la lengua española*.